# Amcharts responsive issue with Pie chart

Tags: pie-chart, amcharts

When we are checking the chart in mobile view, it was showing like in the attached. As a result it is too small to view in mobile.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's very little you can do since a lot of those slices are very small. Just like [my answer to a previous question with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330644/6106614), you can try tweaking the `labelRadius`, `pullOutRadius` and `startAngle` to see if that helps, but you're better off setting a `hideLabelsPercent` to hide those other slices and use a legend for those smaller slices instead. Since you have a lot of slices, you'll want to place the legend in an external div so so it doesn't take up the chart's area by using the legend's [`divId`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#divId) property:

**HTML**

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="legenddiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "legend": {
    "divId": "legenddiv",
     // ...
   },
  // ...
});
```

You can find an example of this in action [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/placing-chart-legend-in-an-external-container/).

You can also try including and enabling [AmCharts' responsive plugin](https://github.com/amcharts/responsive), which comes with some default rules that dynamically change the chart settings in smaller resolutions. You can also add your own rules as well.